# How do I stop Simpleaudio from playing a file twice simulaneously?

Tags: python, audio, simpleaudioengine

I am using simpleaudio in a text-based adventure game. I am using Python 3. In my main loop, I want to achieve this: play a short audio clip, and once it finishes, start playing the same audio clip again. My problem is, that I cannot figure out how to make Simpleaudio do this.

I have read all of the API documentation to no avail. I have tried many different things regarding loops, and none of them work.

```
import simpleaudio as sa

def audio(audiofile):
    filename = "/Users/*********/Desktop/Programming/Python Files/Adventure Game/Audio Files/" + audiofile
    wave_obj = sa.WaveObject.from_wave_file(filename)
    play_obj = wave_obj.play()

A = True
while True:
audio("openingtune.wav")
clear_screen()
firstinput = input("> ")
user_input1(firstinput)

# I didn't include the other functions because they're not relevant to this.
```

Note: the "while true" loop refreshes every so often (after input has been taken, and output has been given). I have no idea how to do this: once the song has finished playing one time, it should start over at the same point.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that the song should be played in the loop regardless of user actions? Currently `audio` sits on the main thread and will wait for `input` and other functions in the loop to complete.

Comment: Yes. Regardless of how users move, the song should keep playing.

Comment: Did the solution work / help you? I noticed you have never accepted any answer, consider reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Lukasz - it never worked. I'm not sure if you saw me say so the first time, but just wanted to let you know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contrary to the suggestions, `simpleaudio` doesn't play the audio on the main thread. Per the docs..

> The module implements an asynchronous interface, meaning that program execution continues immediately after audio playback is started and a background thread takes care of the rest. This makes it easy to incorporate audio playback into GUI-driven applications that need to remain responsive.

The while loop should simply check if the thread has completed and play the audio again if it has.

```
import simpleaudio as sa


class AudioPlayer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.play_obj = None

    def play(audiofile):
        filename = "/Users/*********/Desktop/Programming/Python 
                    Files/Adventure Game/Audio Files/" + audiofile
        wave_obj = sa.WaveObject.from_wave_file(filename)
        self.play_obj = wave_obj.play()
    
    def is_done():
        if self.play_obj:
            return not self.play_obj.is_playing()
        return True

player = AudioPlayer()
while True:
    clear_screen()
    if player.is_done():
        player.play("openingtune.wav")
    ...
```

If you're continuously playing the same file you might want to consider just passing the file string to constructor once and for all. Strings are immutable, so the string in the `player.play()` call is created and passed by copy on every iteration of the loop, which is nuts if it's always the same string.

Answer (score 0):

Your current approach does not work because you play the audio on the main thread. It starts to play audio as intended on the first go, but then there's a sequence of actions after `audio`, i.e. all user input. In the meantime, the `audio` might stop playing and won't be executed until the next pass of the loop.

**Solution: start audio on a separate thread.**

Code:

```
import simpleaudio as sa
from threading import Thread

def audio(audiofile):
    filename = "/Users/*********/Desktop/Programming/Python Files/Adventure Game/Audio Files/" + audiofile
    wave_obj = sa.WaveObject.from_wave_file(filename)
    while(True):
        play_obj = wave_obj.play()

# Let's play the music on a separate thread
audio_thread = Thread(target=audio, args=("openingtune.wav",))
audio_thread.start()

# And now the main game loop
A = True
while True:
    clear_screen()
    firstinput = input("> ")
    user_input1(firstinput)
```

Probably you will want to introduce some controls to stop playing audio.

Comment: This did not work for me. It did this weird thing where it played a distorted version of the audio. It sounded like it was playing itself layered many times, and I don't know why. Please tell me if you have the same problem.